# Iterate a JSON data, put comma after each run and SerializeObject

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am trying to **iterate** (Do While) JSON data input, put **Comma** after each run, and **put [ ]** around at the end.

```cs
var query = new QueryFunction()
{
       Offset = 0,
       PageSize = 2
};
do
{
      query.Offset = offset;
      query.PageSize = pagesize;

      Task<OnlineResponse> task = client.Execute(query);
      OnlineResponse response = task.Result;
      Result result = response.Results[0];

      dynamic resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Data);

      offset += pagesize;
      resultJsonString += resultJson;

      //remaining = result.NumRemaining;
      // Tried to put , after each loop
      //if (remaining == 0)
      //    resultJsonString += resultJson;
      //else
      //    resultJsonString += resultJson + ",";

} while (offset < 4);
return resultJsonString;
```

So, currently, the output for "resultJsonString" is like this as it iterates two times:

As you can see, it put [ ] around each run (**2 output** each time), with no comma after each run.

```
"[{\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264378-1756289-919567\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}},
 {\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264378-1756290-919568-\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}}]
 [{\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264379-1756291-919569\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}},
 {\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264379-1756292-919570\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}}]"
```

Expected output is like this.

```
"[{\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264378-1756289-919567\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}},
 {\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264378-1756290-919568\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}},
 {\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264379-1756291-919569\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}},
 {\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264379-1756292-919570\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}}]"
```

Comment: Add all objects into list/array. After the `do-while` loop ends, serialize the array/list.

Comment: Newtonsoft has `.SupportMultipleContent` to parse multiple json objects from the same stream. For system.text.json there's an open issue; https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/33030.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't append the JSON string manually.

Instead, add the object into the array/list during the iteration in the `do-while` loop.

The `result.Data` returns an array of data, hence you need `List.AddRange()`.

When the loop exits, serialize the array/list.

```cs
using System.Linq;

List<dynamic> resultList = new List<dynamic>();

do
{
    query.Offset = offset;
    query.PageSize = pagesize;

    Task<OnlineResponse> task = client.Execute(query);
    OnlineResponse response = task.Result;
    Result result = response.Results[0];

    offset += pagesize;
    resultList.AddRange(result.Data);

    ...

} while (offset < 4);

resultJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultList);

return resultJsonString;
```

Comment: I am trying to dynamically allocate memory (at List) with current code. How do I go about doing it? Is there anything I could make it perform better?